# Which characters are included in the regex unicode category "Separator"?

Tags: regex, unicode

I'm looking for complete lists of characters in the different regexp Unicode categories, such as `Separator` or `\p{Z}`. Do you know were I can find that or how to generate it myself in a reliable way (with c#). Googling it didn't turn up anything for me.

Comment: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories) links to the [Unicode Charatcer Database](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/). You should be able to generate it from there.

Comment: The number of characters in a category can vary by Unicode version, which version of Unicode are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I found a complete source of all different categories used for Regex (Letters, Numbers, Symbols etc):

https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/extracted/DerivedGeneralCategory.txt

And a source for all different scripts (Latin, Devanagari etc):

https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/

Answer (score 1):

I found this list:
[Separators](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/search?q=Separator#characters)

I simply searched for: 'unicode category Separator'